# SDL OpenGL issue

Tags: opengl, sdl

I am following a tutorial on youtube but the problem is the maker of the tutorial is using SDL 1.2 and Im using 2.00 so i had to change the code up a little bit following the SDL migration guide. However my code isn't doing what its supposed to which is to draw a triangle. Simple as that. All I get is a white screen.

======main============

```
#include "stdafx.h"


void init()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45, 640.0 / 480.0, 1.0, 500.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 2.0, -5.0);
    glVertex3f(-2.0, -2.0, -5.0);
    glVertex3f(2.0, -2.0, -5.0);
    glEnd();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING); 
    SDL_Window * window;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("OpenGLTest", 300, 300, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN |       SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    init();
    SDL_Event * mainEvent;
    mainEvent = new SDL_Event;

    while (true){
        SDL_PollEvent(mainEvent);
        display();
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);

        if (mainEvent->type == SDL_QUIT){
            break;
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```

=====stdafx=========

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>

#define PI 3.14159265

using namespace std;
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try setting a colour with glColor3f or glColor4f

Comment: But isn't supposed to draw a white triangle on a black background? Because background is cleared with black and the default draw color is white?

Comment: I tried. it didnt work

Comment: have you set glViewport(0.f, [windowWidth], [windowHeight], 0.f)?

Comment: No im using gluPerspective

Comment: So?
That function sets the active rendering area, it doesn't enforce any orthagonal matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL` alone is necessary but not sufficient.

Create a GL context with `SDL_GL_CreateContext()` and make it current via `SDL_GL_MakeCurrent()`:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING); 
    SDL_Window * window = SDL_CreateWindow
        (
        "OpenGLTest", 
        300, 300, 
        640, 480, 
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL
        );
    SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext( window );
    SDL_GL_MakeCurrent( window, context );

    glewInit();

    bool running = true;
    while( running )
    {
        SDL_Event ev;
        while( SDL_PollEvent( &ev ) )
        {
            if ( ev.type == SDL_QUIT)
                running = false;
        }

        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(45, 640.0 / 480.0, 1.0, 500.0);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 2.0, -5.0);
        glVertex3f(-2.0, -2.0, -5.0);
        glVertex3f(2.0, -2.0, -5.0);
        glEnd();

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
    }

    SDL_GL_DeleteContext( context );
    SDL_DestroyWindow( window );
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user3161752: If that fixed your problem, then an up-vote / accept is the proper course of action on Stack Overflow. Q&A only works when the person who asked the Q accepts an A ;)

Comment: sorry i cant up yet cuz I dont have enought reputation but I picked your answer

Comment: In my case, I (accidentally) added `SDL_RenderPresent()` after `SDL_GL_SwapWindow()`.  Remove it fix for me.  Thank genpfault for the full demo.